# Proof verification: Let $f$ be continuous on open set $D$ and of class $C^{(1)}$ on $D-\{\bf{x_0}\}$. Show $f$ is of class $C^{(1)}$ on $D$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

The following proof exercises is taken from Wendell Fleming's functions of several variables (page 99).

> Let $f$ be continuous on open set $D$ and of class $C^{(1)}$ on $D-\{\bf{x_0}\}$. Suppose moreover that $l_{i}=\lim_{\bf{x} \to \bf{x_{0}}}f_{i}(\bf{x})$ exists for each $i=1, \dots ,n$. Prove that $l_{i}=f_{i}(\bf{x_0})$ and consequently $f$ is of class $C^{(1)}$ on $D$. State and prove the corresponding result for $q>1$. (Hint: Apply the mean value theorem to $f({\bf{x_0}}+t{\bf{e_i}})-f(\bf{x_0})$ )

As I've been getting serious about learning and writing proofs myself, I would like for you to verify/ comment on my proof.

$\it\text{Proof:}$ Using the hint, by the continuity of $f$ on $D$, we may apply MVT to the following:
$$f({\bf{x_0}}+t{\bf{e_i}})-f(\bf{x_0})$$
provided $|{\bf{e_{i}}}|=1$ and $t$ such that ${\bf{x_0}}+t{\bf{e_i}} \in D$. By MVT:
$$f({\bf{x_0}}+t{\bf{e_i}})-f({\bf{x_0}})=df({\bf{x_0}}+st{\bf{e_i}}) \cdot t{\bf{e_i}}$$
for $s \in (0,1)$. Henceforth,
\begin{align}
\frac{f({\bf{x_0}}+t{\bf{e_i}})-f({\bf{x_0}})}{t}&=df({\bf{x_0}}+st{\bf{e_i}}) \cdot {\bf{e_i}}\\
&=f_{i}({\bf{x_0}}+st{\bf{e_i}})
\end{align}
For ${\bf{x}} \to {\bf{x_0}}$ in $f_{i}({\bf{x_0}}+st{\bf{e_i}})$ , we require $t \to 0$.
$$\lim_{\bf{x} \to \bf{x_{0}}}f_{i}({\bf{x}})=\lim_{t \to 0} f_{i}({\bf{x_0}}+st{\bf{e_i}})=f_{i}({\bf{x_0}})$$
by the above and by the existence of the limit. This shows $l_{i}=f_{i}(\bf{x_0})$ and consequently $f$ is of class $C^{(1)}$ on $D$.

We prove the version for $q>1$, i.e

> Let $f$ be continuous on open set $D$ and of class $C^{(q)}$ on $D-\{\bf{x_0}\}$. Suppose moreover that $l_{i}=\lim_{\bf{x} \to \bf{x_{0}}}f_{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q}}(\bf{x})$ exists for each $i=1, \dots ,n$. Prove that $l_{i}=f_{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q}}(\bf{x_0})$ and consequently $f$ is of class $C^{(1)}$ on $D$.

I used the same notation as Fleming, being that $f_{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q}}$ denotes the $q$th order derivative of $f$ taken with respect to directions $i_{1},\dots ,i_{q}$.

${\it\text{Proof}}$: We induct on $q$ in $C^{(q)}$, where the first proof shows the case for $q=1$. Suppose the proposition holds for $q-1$, meaning that the following expression must be continuous:
$$f_{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q-1}}({\bf{x_0}}+t{\bf{e_i}})-f_{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q-1}}(\bf{x_0})$$
Thus, we may apply MVT,
\begin{align}
f_{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q-1}}({\bf{x_0}}+t{\bf{e_i}})-f_{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q-1}}(\bf{x_0}) &= df_{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q}}({\bf{x_0}}+st{\bf{e_i}}) \cdot t{\bf{e_i}} \\
\frac{f_{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q-1}}({\bf{x_0}}+t{\bf{e_i}})-f_{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q-1}}(\bf{x_0})}{t} &= df_{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q}}({\bf{x_0}}+st{\bf{e_i}}) \cdot {\bf{e_i}} \\
&=f_{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q}}({\bf{x_0}}+st{\bf{e_i}})
\end{align}
for $s \in (0,1)$. For ${\bf{x}} \to {\bf{x_0}}$ in $f_{{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q}}}({\bf{x_0}}+st{\bf{e_i}})$ , we require $t \to 0$.
$$\lim_{\bf{x} \to \bf{x_{0}}}f_{{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q}}}({\bf{x}})=\lim_{t \to 0} f_{{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q}}}({\bf{x_0}}+st{\bf{e_i}})=f_{{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q}}}({\bf{x_0}})$$
as shown by the above and since the limit exists. Thus, by induction hypothesis, we are done.

Thoughts on my proof? Is it correct?

Comment: Misprint at the end of your sentence to prove for $q>1$: replace $C^{(1)}$ by $C^{(q)}.$ Also, you should make explicit in the hypothesis that $f$ is real-valued (and not vector-valued).

Comment: The induction step can be shortened: don't re-prove the case $q=1.$ Just apply it to the function $f_{i_{1},\dots ,i_{q-1}}.$ Apart from that, everything fine.

Comment: @AnneBauval will do! Thank you!